# PHP найти в тесте класс и присвоить содержимое тегов переменной

Tags: php, wordpress, регулярные-выражения, классы, поиск

Во всех текстах (посты в Wordpress) есть слова (в моем случае просто название компаний) в тегах  c классом "tr-stock-ticker". задача состоит в следующем: реализовать поиск в тексте этого класса и присвоит значение в тегах спана переменной $ticker. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

UPD: Полный отрывок с кодом:

```
if(!$isHome && !$isArticle && empty($args['force'])){preg_match_all("/<.*?class=\"tr-stock-ticker\">(.*?)<\//", $post->post_content, $out);
$ticker = array_map(function ($s) {
return strip_tags($s);}, $out[1]);
echo $args['before_widget'];
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

$sector = tr_get_sector($post_id);
}
else{
echo $args['before_widget'];
if (!empty($title))
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
$ticker = tr_get_ticker($post_id);}
```

Должен выводить в виджете под постом название компании:
[сам сайт](https://www.smarteranalyst.com/brief/floor-decor-holdings-inc-fnd-receives-a-buy-from-wells-fargo-2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/<.*?class=\"tr-stock-ticker\">(.*?)<\//", $text, $out);
$ticker = $out[1];
```

UPD:

> Возможно сделать поиск по спану, в которых, блин, еще и ссылки хранятся?

Ну если не мудрить, и так сойдет)

```
preg_match_all("/<.*?class=\"tr-stock-ticker\">(.*?)<\//", $text, $out);

$ticker = array_map(function ($s) {
    return strip_tags($s);
}, $out[1]);
```

UPD 2:

> тэг один на пост, а в строке лишь одно слово

```
preg_match_all("/<.*?class=\"tr-stock-ticker\">(.*?)<\//", $text, $out);
if (count($out[1])) {
    $ticker = strip_tags($out[1][0]);
} else {
    $ticker = "";
}
```

UPD 3:

```
preg_match_all("/<[^\/>]+?class=[\"']tr-stock-ticker[\"'][^\/>]*?>(.*?)<\//", $content, $out);
if (count($out[1])) {
    $ticker = strip_tags($out[1][0]);
} else {
    $ticker = "";
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85216/discussion-on-answer-by---php-------).